# How to get a pcap file with traceroute icmp type 30

Tags: networking, wireshark, pcap, icmp, traceroute

I'm writing a program to analyze network traffic.

Therefore I want to check the ICMP Type 30 (traceroute). I can't find a pcap file for this case. If I traceroute some website with cmd (traceroute stackoverflow.com), I get only ICMP type 0, 3, 8 and 11.

How can I get a pcap file with traceroute type 30?

Comment: It sounds like your traceroute is failing, you are getting destination unreachable and timeout packets. But, are you running the traceroute in a command line and watching it succeed while your analysis doesn't seem to pick up the correct packets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ICMP Type 30 is [deprecated.](http://www.iana.org/assignments/icmp-parameters/icmp-parameters.xhtml#icmp-parameters-codes-30)

Traceroute programs send either ICMP echo requests (type 8) or UDP packets. The packets are sent with low TTL values, triggering routers to respond with ICMP type 11 (Time Exceeded) packets.